# How to close the Websocket connection when an exception occurs and pass the exception message to the client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

**Context:**

We are using Websockets in our ASP.NET Core 2 MVC app. This is our code in our Startup.cs class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    [...]

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            if(context.Request.Path == "/ws")
            {
                WebSocket lWebSocket =  await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

                // a custom class that handles the websocket request → perhaps replace by an action controller.
                var lHandleWebSocket = new HandleWebSocket();

                await lHandleWebSocket.HandleConnection(context, lWebSocket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data transfer will be handled by the class 'HandleConnection':

```
public async Task HandleConnection(HttpContext context, WebSocket pWebSocket)
{
    var lBuffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult lWebSocketReceiveResult = null;
    string lTmpString = string.Empty;

    // get next values
    lWebSocketReceiveResult = await pWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(lBuffer), CancellationToken.None);

    // Doing something here...

    // close connection
    await pWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, "TestError", CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Here is a small snippet about the used JavaScript:

```
self.WebSocketChat = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws");
self.WebSocketChat.onclose = function (data) { console.log(data); }; 
self.WebSocketChat.onerror = function (data) { console.log(data); };
```

Description: The client connects with the server. When the client sends the first message to the Server, then the server closes the connection. In the client the 'onclose'-event fires as expected and prints the following information to the console:

```
Console: CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: true, code: 1011, reason: "TestError", type: "close", …}
```

All is working as expected.

**Problem:**

Now we want to close the websocket connection when an exception occurs on server-side. We want to pass the message and callstack of the exception into the closing frame.

Catch Exceptions in the Startup.cs-File:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    [...]

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            if(context.Request.Path == "/ws")
            {
                WebSocket lWebSocket =  await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

                // a custom class that handles the websocket request → perhaps replace by an action controller.
                var lHandleWebSocket = new HandleWebSocket();

                try
                {
                    await lHandleWebSocket.HandleConnection(context, lWebSocket);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // close connection
                    await lWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, e.ToString(), CancellationToken.None);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Throw an exception:

```
public async Task HandleConnection(HttpContext context, WebSocket pWebSocket)
{
    var lBuffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult lWebSocketReceiveResult = null;
    string lTmpString = string.Empty;

    // get next values
    lWebSocketReceiveResult = await pWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(lBuffer), CancellationToken.None);

    // throw an exception
    throw new TestException("TestException");
}
```

When we send an message now to the server, the TestException will be thrown and catched as expected:

[image]

But on client-side the 'onclose'-Event does not fire.

```
self.WebSocketChat.onclose = function (data) { console.log(data); }; // nothing happens
```

Also the '.onerror' event does not fire.

**Question:**

How to close the Websocket connection when an exception occurs and pass the exception message to the client?